# What should you do if you have an interface with a collection of objects and you want both a read-only and a read-write version of the interface?

Tags: c#

I'm currently creating some interfaces for user controls that will contain collections of objects. I want to have an interface for a control that can have objects added from the outside, and another interface for one that cannot have objects added from the outside. So far I basically have the following (simplified for this question; if it would help you to see the actual code I have thus far please let me know):

```
public interface IReadableFoo 
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<Foo> Foos { get; }
}

public interface IReadWriteFoo : IReadOnlyFoo 
{
    new ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; }
}
```

**What is considered the "best practice" to do in this situation where you have an interface with a collection of objects, and you want to have both a read-only version and a read-write version?** Is it considered acceptable to have an `ICollection<Foo>` shadowing an `IReadOnlyCollection<Foo>` like that?

Is there some other pattern I should be using instead? Should `IReadOnlyFoo` and `IReadWriteFoo` both inherit from a common base interface `IFoo`?

Edit: To clarify what I am trying to do, I'm adding the actual code that I'm working with here:

```
public interface IOptionSelector<T>
{

    IReadOnlyCollection<T> Options { get; }
    T SelectedOption { get; }
    event EventHandler SelectedOptionChanged;
}

public interface IWriteableOptionSelector<T> : IOptionSelector<T>
{
    new ICollection<T> Options { get; }
    new T SelectedOption { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why does IReadWriteFoo need to inherit from IReadOnlyFoo?

Comment: Make two separate interfaces?

Comment: @KiwiPiet Because I want to be able read values from all Foos, not just read-only foos. These interfaces represent user controls that will be used to select an object from a group of objects (think a group of radio buttons or dropdown list). Some Foos can only be set by the user clicking on them, others can be set from code as well. But all of them can have their collections read. If I make a FooReader(IReadableFoo) method I want to be able to read *all* foos, whether they're read-write or read-only.

Comment: make them seperate. Don't do inheritance from each other.

Comment: Anything but `new` :)... For read-only version consider if `IEnumerable<T>` works - it is inherently read-only and you don't need to explain anyone why there are 2 collections in "writable" interface.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Wait, I don't understand how using `IEnumerable<T>` would fix anything. I'd still end up with the `Foos` property of `IWriteableOptionSelector<T>` shadowing the `Foos` property of `IOptionSelector<T>`.

Comment: @Codonbyte - I think you still should have 2 distinct methods/properties - or the same property on unrelated interfaces... Just `IEnumerable` does not need explanation about it being read-only and does not pretend to be anything more that just a sequence.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know that `IEnumerable` is a sequence without add/remove methods etc. I was confused because I thought you were saying that changing the type of the `Foos` property from `IReadOnlyCollection<Foo>` to `IEnumerable<Foo>` would fix my problem, and I tried doing that and still got the compiler warning about member hiding. After your comment about "`IEnumerable` not needing explanation" I'm guessing that you were not saying that using `IEnumerable would fix the problem I have at hand, so nevermind that.

Comment: I don't know why you want your writeable interface to inherit from the read-only version. But note that .NET itself does something similar with the collections, e.g. `List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>`. More to the point here, do you have a question besides "what should I do?" Something _specific_ that could produce a good, useful answer?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I want my writeable interface to inherit from the read-only version because the writeable interface _has all the functionality of the read-only version_. Read-only version can read; read-write version can read _and write_. Hence, a read-write interface can be passed into a method expecting read-only interface _because it does everything the read-only interface does_. That's the whole point of interfaces, is it not? To classify objects by what they **do**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
public interface IOptionSelector<T>
{
    event EventHandler SelectedOptionChanged;
}
public interface IReadOnlyOptionSelector<T> : IOptionSelector<T>
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<T> Options { get; }
}
public interface IWritableOptionsSelector<T> : IOptionSelector<T>
{
    ICollection<T> Options { get; }
}
```

ReadOnly and Writeable are two separate concerns.  When you have to use the new keyword on methods that you wrote that is a clear indication that you are dealing with separate concerns and need to rethink your design.